# onChanged function in Observer MutableLive Data behaves unusual for the 2nd call in android MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

My application integrated with MVVM + retrofit + dagger

when it comes to ViewModel i have used MutableLiveData to register observer with Fragment and ViewModel

So when the view loads it calls the view model and calls the web service then `onChnaged` function of observer will poppulates data , But when i add a button click and calls the same function it behaves unusual here is the code sample.

```
 ViewModel
 private MediatorLiveData<Resource<PostCartResponse>> postCartResponse
            = new MediatorLiveData<>();
     public LiveData<Resource<PostCartResponse>> postProductToCart(
                final PostCart postCart) {
            postCartResponse.addSource(this.cartRepository.postCart(postCart),
                    new Observer<Resource<PostCartResponse>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable Resource<PostCartResponse> response) {
                            postCartResponse.setValue(response);
                        }
                    });
            return postCartResponse;
        }
Fragment
productDetailsViewModel.postProductToCart(new PostCart(1, generatedSku))
                .observe(this, new Observer<Resource<PostCartResponse>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(@Nullable Resource<PostCartResponse> response) {

                        if (response.status == Status.SUCCESS) {
                            Timber.d("SUCCESS");
                        } else if (response.status == Status.INVALID_DATA) {
                            Timber.d("FAIL");
                        }

                    }
                });
```

So for the first time it properly calls and  log SUCCESS but lets say if i press the button again , initially it prints the SUCCESS in fragment then again it prints the SUCCESS

Any idea for this unusual behaviour .

Answer (score 0):

Well after reading about MutableLiveData this seems like the natural behaviour of it,  addSource will register the invoker and onChanged will executes each time you register.
So i made a small research about it  Apparently in MVVM to do app sample there is a new class called `SingleLiveEvent`

> A lifecycle-aware observable that sends only new updates after
>   subscription, used for events like navigation and Snackbar messages.
>
> This avoids a common problem with events: on configuration change
>   (like rotation) an update can be emitted if the observer is active.
>   This LiveData only calls the observable if there's an explicit call to
>   setValue() or call().

So using this i managed to get it done